# Share data in a clustered environment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, cluster-computing, ehcache

I am in the process of migrating my Spring MVC + Hibernate web app to clustered environment (Tomcat clustering). In the application, I store some lookup tables in class static variables, whenever there is a change, I just reload the table into the variables (mostly HashMap), the change is then immediately reflected in all parts of the application. Obviously it won't work in a clustered environment as the static variables are only accessible in a single JVM. I was thinking about using Ehcache with replication. However I just did a test of Ehcache replication and found out that two nodes of Ehcache may contain inconsistent data. For example, I put number 1, 2, 3 ... into node1, and disconnected node1 and node2 for a while, then reconnect, I found out the elements put into node1 during the disconnected period are missing from node2. That is okay for a cache. However I want changes made on one server immediately reflected to another server in the cluster. So the end user can have same experience as before. Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Did you take a look at Redis? You can use Redis as cache/key-value data store without the hassle of multicast, cluster synchronisation etc.

Comment: Have you tried simply not caching at all? Your database is fast, and lookup tables are small. Queries for these tables should be fast.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll take a look of Redis, I know Spring Session use it as a backend repository.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for Terracotta

You can cluster Ehcache with [Terracotta](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog). Version 4.3.0 has again an open-source option.

As you have noticed in your tests, the replication option in Ehcache 2.x does not offer any consistency guarantees.
The clustering option however will be able to give you just that.